# Cabal Configure fails on Configuring test (Windows)

Tags: windows, testing, haskell, cabal, yesod

I am new to Haskell and trying to install Yesod on a windows machine using cabal.

When I try to do a `yesod devel` I get a build failure, saing I must run configure first.

Then when I run a `cabal configure` it fails with the following message:

```
Resolving dependencies...
Configuring test-0.0.0...
cabal: Test sharing name of exe found. Consider this a bug.
```

I am using the latest Haskell platform (2012.2.0.0).

Comment: That isn't the http://www.yesodweb.com/page/quickstart way.

Comment: I am following the quickstart step-by-step..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently there's a bug in cabal, and you can't have a test executable with the same name as a regular executable. Since the test executable is named `test`, and the regular executable has the same name as your project, it would appear that `test` is no longer a valid name for a Yesod project. If you name it something else, it should work.

Could you file a bug report on Github so that we prevent people from using the name `test`?

Comment: Ah, didn't consider the name of the project at all :)